# Getting a Parameter Source Error Creating Search on Index Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, razor-pages, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to create a search that has a starting and ending date range along with a dropdown list where the user can select one (or more) municipalities to return on the Index page search. The date search alone works great, but when I try to add the dropdown (an additional request from the users), I am getting the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

```
Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
    System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
    System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<TElement, TKey>..ctor(IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending, OrderedEnumerable<TElement> parent)
    System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    Referrals.Pages.Reports.AllMunisListing.Pages_Reports_AllMunisListing_Index.<ExecuteAsync>b__21_1()...
```

Here is the portion of my index.cshtml where the issue is:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <p>
                <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                            Select Beginning Date Received: <input type="date" name="startdate" value="" /> and Ending Date Received: <input type="date" name="enddate" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">
                            Select Municipality(ities):
                            <select asp-for="TempData" name="searchmuni" id="Select1" style="width: 250px" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayRefMunis.OrderBy(x => x.Id),"Name", "Name"))"><option value="Name" selected disabled>---Select Municipality(ies)---</option></select>
                        </td>
                        <td width="75%">
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" />
                            <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-link mx-2">Return to Full List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
            </p>
        </div>
```

and here is my .cs behind it:

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Referrals.Pages.Reports.AllMunisListing;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Referral> Results { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplayRefMunis { get; set; }

    public string DateReceivedSort { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Results = _db.Referral.ToList();

        await _db.Municipality.Select(a => a.Name).ToListAsync();
        DisplayRefMunis = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string searchmuni, string sortOrder)
    {
        Results = (from x in _db.Referral where (x.DateReceived >= startdate) && (x.DateReceived <= enddate) && x.RefMunicipality.Contains(searchmuni) select x).ToList();

        DateReceivedSort = sortOrder == "DateReceived_Asc_Sort" ? "DateReceived_Desc_Sort" : "DateReceived_Asc_Sort";

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "DateReceived_Asc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
            case "DateReceived_Desc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
            default:
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
        }

        DisplayRefMunis = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

        TempData["StartDate"] = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        TempData["EndDate"] = enddate.ToShortDateString();
        TempData["SearchMuni"] = searchmuni.ToString();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I am still relatively new to coding and figure I've likely missed a step, having something additional I shouldn't have, etc. Not sure I have the dropdown set up correctly for more than one selection (although it lets me select more than one).

I have searched here and looked through several other posts that have this parameter error, but do not understand all of the replies or how they could apply to my own instance. If someone could please take a look and assist me, I would much appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a cookie issue : "Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing"  See : https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/cookies

Comment: @jdweng Thank you. Could you please elaborate. I read the link, but not sure I understand. Do I need to set the cookies to expire sooner? What is it that I need to do with them? Disable, enable, expire? I don't understand what the problem with the cookie is.

Comment: @jdweng "Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing" are the tab headings on the standard developer error page. Looks to me like they've been included in the error message copy/paste.

Comment: @MikeBrind : The old cookies are being used and the code has changed.  The old cookies need to be updated

Comment: @jdweng There are no cookies in the OPs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to repopulate `DisplayRefMunis` in your `OnPost` handler. The framework tries to redisplay the page with the form including the select options which don't exist.

Each request to the page is separate and no state is maintained between requests, so you must ensure that all data needed for the page is prepared regardless of the HTTP method used to request the page.

Copy the line

```
DisplayRefMunis = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
```

to the `OnPost` handler to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you, except now I apparently have another issue. Should I address it here or in another post? The Search only returns the first municipality that I select, not ALL of the ones I select, so apparently is a single-select. What do I have to change to make it multi-select?

Comment: I have updated the .cs with my code change.

Comment: Thinking to myself, but don't know how to do it in code. Do I need to iterate through the selected dropdowns? So that once it accepts the first selected one, it knows to look for more selections?

Comment: @MelB Yes, you should post this as another question.